# Python open and saving multiple files using loops

Tags: python

Below is a code that will open a source file, and copy it to a template and then save the files as a new name. I would like to add multiple for loops to this script.

I have 27 files that I want to open, and paste to the template individually and save as different names each time.

I don't want to have to input the sources file name each time, and update the save each time. I'm not sure how to go about modifying the below script to make this work.

```
Examples Source Files:
NNB-6a_v1_T01-Report.xlsx
NNB-6a_v1_T02-Report.xlsx
NNB-6a_v1_T03-Report.xlsx
NNB-6a_v1_P01-Report.xlsx
NNB-6a_v1_P02-Report.xlsx
NNB-6a_v1_P03-Report.xlsx

Paste source data one by one into template - then save each as

Example Save as:
Report_6a_v1_T01.xlsx
Report_6a_v1_T02.xlsx
Report_6a_v1_T03.xlsx
Report_6a_v1_P01.xlsx
Report_6a_v1_P02.xlsx
Report_6a_v1_P03.xlsx

     import openpyxl as xl; 
        import glob
        import pandas as pd



        # opening the source excel file 
        filename ="C:/NNB-6a_v1_T01-Report.xlsx"
        wb1 = xl.load_workbook(filename) 
        ws1 = wb1.worksheets[1] 

        # opening the destination excel file  
        filename1 ="C:/Template.xlsx"
        wb2 = xl.load_workbook(filename1) 
        ws2 = wb2.worksheets[2] 

        # calculate total number of rows and  
        # columns in source excel file 
        mr = ws1.max_row 
        mc = ws1.max_column 

        # copying the cell values from source  
        # excel file to destination excel file 
        for i in range (1, mr + 1): 
            for j in range (1, mc + 1): 
                # reading cell value from source excel file 
                c = ws1.cell(row = i, column = j) 

                ws2.cell(row = i+12, column = j+1).value = c.value 

        # saving the destination excel file 
        wb2.save('C:/Report_6a_v1_T01.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your files are in directory `dir`, you can use `os` package, to fetch the names of files in a list. Since you are only looking for `xlsx` files, it would be appropriate to filter the file names with accordingly. Once you have the names of files in a list, you can loop through it, and do your excel operations:
Sample code:

```
import os
#import rest of the pkgs

#fetch the filenames from current directory
files = [file for file in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(file) and file.endswith('.xlsx')]

#make a separate directory for reports
os.mkdir('./reports')

for file in files:
    #loop through files and do your operation
    #save to reports directory
    report_name = file + '_report'
    wb.save('./reports/'+report_name+'.xlsx')
```

Comment: Where does +report_name+ get defined?

Comment: It is just a pseudo variable to represent any file name that you want to save with. If you already have report names, you can iterate through files and report names simultaneously and save. Edited the code, to include report_name.